# How to get previously clicked menu in MDI form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menu, mdi

I am developing Windows Application. In that, I have MDI form with several menu items.

i.g.

```
File              Windows
--> Open          -->Form1
--> Save          -->Form2 
--> Exit
```

Now user first clicks on "Form1" and then Clicks on "Form2". Now my question is, can i get previously clicked menu i.g. "Form1" in MDI Form? Is there any event or any method to find out the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should use public variable in project and like these

```
Module Module1
 Public current As String
 Public prev As String
End Module
```

and then when you click menu item use these code to save prev menu item clicked

```
prev = current
current = "Current Menu Item Name"
```